# Как добавить попадающие в папку файлы в формате json в отдельный массив?

Tags: php, массивы, post, get

Пользователь подгружает json файлы (тесты) в директорию на сервере. Названия файлов отображаются на экране. Как мне автоматически туда попадющие json файлы запихнуть в массив, чтобы потом к ним отдельно через форму обращаться по индексу (индекс 1 = загрузка теста 1, и так допустим до 10).

```
<?php
$dir ='uploads/';
$list=scandir($dir);
$z=count(scandir('uploads/'))-1;
$x=2;
do {
    echo $list[$x],"  ", "  - Number ", $x-1, "</br>"; 

}   while ($x++<$z);
?>
```

Comment: Периодически проверять папку на новые json. В случае обнаружения, отсортировать их по дате, например, загонять в массив и помечать/удалять уже загнанные. Когда закончатся, снова мониторить с интервалом папку на предмет новых json (старые либо удалены, либо как-то помечены, чтобы не учитываться). В случае обнаружения повторяем действия.

Comment: Хм, а попроще никак?) Например каждому доку каким-то образом задать порядковый номер, чтобы его можно было вызывать из другого файла например?

Comment: не совсем понял а что именно сложно в предложенном способе? Вам всё равно надо мониторить папку на добавление новых файлов. Разве что вы сможете подписаться как-то на событие появления новых файлов в папке =/